# Reading only data added since last ready from buffer in golang

Tags: go

I am writing a program that uses SSH shells to execute a series of commands, some of which are long-running. The below function successfully reads the output until an end condition is reached, however each time I read the buffer I get all of the output since the command starting running, which I don't really need. Is there a way to only get the data added to the buffer since the last read?

```golang
func RunLongSSHCommand(o *bytes.Buffer, stdin io.Writer, command string, end string) bool {
    _, err := fmt.Fprintf(stdin, "%s\n", command)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    o.Reset()
    log.Info("buffer:", o.String())
    log.Println("Command: ", command)

    for {
        done := false
        scanner := bufio.NewScanner(o)
        for scanner.Scan() {
            fmt.Println(scanner.Text())
            if strings.Contains(scanner.Text(), end) {
                fmt.Println(scanner.Text())
                done = true
                break
            }
        }
        if done {
            break
        }
        //o.Reset()
        //log.Info("buffer:", o.String())
        time.Sleep(3 * time.Second)

    }
    return true
}
```

Code that creates buffer:

```golang
   

     sess, client := ssh_ftp.SshConnect(dev3)
        defer client.Close()
        defer sess.Close()
        // StdinPipe for commands
    
    stdin, err := sess.StdinPipe()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    
        // Start remote shell
    err = sess.Shell()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    
        // Uncomment to store output in variable
    var b bytes.Buffer
    sess.Stdout = &b
    sess.Stderr = &b
```

New problem: The scan of the stdout pipe only breaks with a manual end condition, otherwise it hangs. Is there a way to avoid having a manual end condition?

```golang
func RunLongSSHCommand(stdout io.Reader, stdin io.Writer, command string, end string) bool {

    _, err := fmt.Fprintf(stdin, "%s\n", command)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    log.Println("Command: ", command)

    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(stdout)

    print("scanning output")
    for scanner.Scan() {
        fmt.Println(scanner.Text())

        if strings.Contains(scanner.Text(), end) {
            fmt.Println("end")
            //done = true
            break
        }

    }

    print("done")
    return true
}
```

function call :

```golang
RunLongSSHCommand(stdout, stdin, command, "Removing Workstation")
```

pipe declaration.

```golang
stdout, err := sess.StdoutPipe()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
```

Comment: The program probably has a data race on the bytes.Buffer.  Get an `*os.File` on output and scan that until the end condition is found.

Comment: @CeriseLimón How would I do that? (I am still pretty new to Go)

Comment: @Gavin I am because that buffer is hooked to the Stdout of the ssh session.

Comment: @snvgglebear It's difficult to provide specific guidance without seeing the relevant code.  It may be that you need a net.Conn instead of a *os.File.  Show the code the where you create the bytes.Buffer.

Comment: @CeriseLimón Added as an edit to the post.

Comment: Read from a pipe created from `sess.StdoutPipe()`.

Comment: @CeriseLimón New problem explained in the edit above where bufio.scanner.scan hangs without manual break condition.